# Order By in Ascending Order

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

i have used the following query for POPUP LOV in Apex

```
select VEN_INVOICE_REFNO as display_value, VEN_INVOICE_REFNO as return_value 
  from VENDORINVOICE
 order by 1 asc;
```

i want to show me the values as shown in diagram in numeric order i-e in ascending order.i have tried all the possible ways which i know but it don't  works.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seem that your field datatype is string, convert it into numeric then apply the `order by`

```
select CAST(VEN_INVOICE_REFNO AS INTEGER) as display_value, VEN_INVOICE_REFNO as return_value 
 from VENDORINVOICE
 order by 1 asc;
```

Comment: it is varchar because sometimes 'VEN_INVOICE_REFNO' can have value other than numeric

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
select VEN_INVOICE_REFNO as display_value, VEN_INVOICE_REFNO as return_value 
  from VENDORINVOICE
 order by ORDER BY CAST(`display_value` AS SIGNED)
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember I had this issue once, and I ended up multiplying it by 1

something like that (Not sure if it will work, you might need to cast your VEN_INVOICE_REFNO it to numeric)

```
select (VEN_INVOICE_REFNO * 1) as display_value, VEN_INVOICE_REFNO as return_value 
  from VENDORINVOICE
 order by 1 asc;
```

of like this:

```
select CONVERT((VEN_INVOICE_REFNO * 1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) as display_value, VEN_INVOICE_REFNO as return_value 
  from VENDORINVOICE
 order by 1 asc;
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew your 1st query works but second one have some error ..Missing Right Parenthesis ..i think Parenthesis are Ok

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions here will not work if any of the records have a non-numeric value, so FWIW here is an alternative solution:

```
select VEN_INVOICE_REFNO as display_value, VEN_INVOICE_REFNO as return_value 
from VENDORINVOICE
order by LPAD(VEN_INVOICE_REFNO,100,' ') asc;
```

Just change `100` to the maximum size of the column.

However, my solution will not work if the column has any negative or decimal (floating-point) numeric values.

Comment: ...Thanks. may i have your Skype id.i am having some problem in accounts so  that i can chat u there and discuss with you.

Comment: Sure, but please be aware that I do charge by the hour for one-to-one service. And my fees are quite high, payable in advance and non-refundable. If this is acceptable, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try this

> select VEN_INVOICE_REFNO as display_value, VEN_INVOICE_REFNO as return_value 
>     from VENDORINVOICE
>    order by VEN_INVOICE_REFNO